# "Unable to find component name" on myodbc-installer of driver

Tags: mysql-connector, unixodbc

Trying to follow [the directions for installing the MySQL ODBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-unix-tarball.html).

When I try to run:

```
myodbc-installer -a -d -n "MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver" -t "Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc8w.so"
```

It says:

> [ERROR] SQLInstaller error 6: Unable to find component name

I've found a handful of cases of people reporting this same message, e.g., [here](https://community.tableau.com/thread/280784) and [here](https://community.tableau.com/thread/280784).  Yet there seems to be no resolution.

Noticing the slight variations in the `-n` name string for the various drivers, I wondered if perhaps the name was something subtly different and the documentation hadn't been updated.  But I used a hex editor to look in `/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc8w.so` and the literal string "MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver" is in it.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some instances of a name mismatch causing the problem (e.g. in one of the linked-to cases, they use `-n "MySQL"` instead of the prescribed `-n "MySQL ODBC 5.3"` from the notes).

However...in my case it was a matter of not using `sudo`.  The error message is not very helpful in indicating that the problem could be a matter of privileges! :-/  But at the very top of the [linked instruction page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-unix-tarball.html) it says (emphasis mine):

> To install the driver from a tarball distribution (.tar.gz file), download the latest version of the driver for your operating system and follow these steps, substituting the appropriate file and directory names based on the package you download (**some of the steps below might require superuser privileges**)

What's going on is that unixodbc has system-wide `odbcinst.ini` and `odbc.ini`.  It is stated that you should not be editing these files directly, but they are edited via an API that unixodbc provides.  That API is called by the MySQL helper utility called `myodbc-installer`:

- The error message is delivered by this [`print_installer_error()`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-odbc/blob/cd3aad7a64a2c6bf58c6b04e0a63026bbacc8189/installer/myodbc-installer.cc#L211) routine
- ...which is called from [`add_driver()`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-odbc/blob/cd3aad7a64a2c6bf58c6b04e0a63026bbacc8189/installer/myodbc-installer.cc#L382) when the routine `SQLInstallDriverExW()` returns false

*(Note: unixodbc on most platforms provides the (W)ide Character version of `SQLInstallDriverEx()`, but `myodbc-installer` defines its own `SQLInstallDriverExW()` if it is not available [via a shim](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-odbc/blob/cd3aad7a64a2c6bf58c6b04e0a63026bbacc8189/installer/myodbc-installer.cc#L290).)*

This API apparently doesn't have a way of saying it can't get the necessary privileges to the files (in `/usr/local/etc` or perhaps just in `/etc`).  So `myodbc-installer` is just parroting what it got.  Sigh.